# getElementsByClassName returns an array but some members are undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am using `document.getElementsByClassName('pattern-checkbox')` to get the `patterns` array here.

[image: pattern array dropdown]

Any suggestion why some of the elements are undefined? I can see, for example, `25-pattern-checkbox` exists in the DOM.

[image: dom list]

The only thing unusual that I can think of is that these `input` fields are not visible, but part of a dropdown menu that is closed at the time of searching.

Comment: Your getElementsByClassName is going to return all elements from the document/page - visible or not.  If the page has undefined elements, you can filter out undefined elements or target a specific area by getting a specific element first to search through.

Comment: Thanks, @JoshAdams. I know I can limit the scope, or check for undefined, but I'm trying to understand how an existing dom element can be undefined, such as my example of `25-pattern-checkbox` above. This is listed as `undefined`, yet it is definitely one of the fields I need to check.

Comment: Ahh, sorry about that! when are you executing your script? Are you waiting for the dom to completely load first before? Also looks like the input tag does not have a value set?

Comment: The script is executing on a custom "Submit" button that will call Ajax with the results (after I have ticked off some boxes, not others). It's a pretty complex page, which is why I wasn't using a straight-up `form`. And I only need to know the `checked` value of each, so do I need to set a value?

Comment: I think this might be a debugging bug in MS Edge browser. If I save each value to a new variable, they exist even if a moment before they were "undefined".

Comment: Interesting, wonder if you get the same result in different browser? I'm glad you have it working now though! Best of luck to you my friend.

Comment: Yep, different result in Chrome! I’ll add an answer in a bit.

Comment: The elements aren't really undefined, notice that it shows their IDs. This is clearly just a console glitch.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out this is a bug in the MS Edge browser debugger console. Different result in Chrome.